# How to Automate facebook login test using Appium in Android

Tags: android, facebook, automated-tests, appium

Hi I am new to Appium testing. I am testing facebook login in my app but the problem is I am not able to select the ids in UIAutomatorViewer as it will open the facebook webview.So I tried switching the context from NATIVE to WEB but still its not working.

Here is the code

```
    public void fbLogin() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("IN FB_LOGIN TEST ");
    this.getDriver().context("NATIVE_APP");// set the context to Native
    _fb_sign_in_button.click(); // click on the fb button in native app
    Thread.sleep(10000); // sleep
    Set<String> contextNames = getDriver().getContextHandles();
    for (String contextName : contextNames) {
        System.out.println(contextName);
        if (contextName.contains("WEBVIEW")) {
            getDriver().context(contextName);
        }
    }
    this.getDriver().findElementByXPath("//android.widget.EditText[@index='0']").sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");
```

can some one suggest whats going wrong?

Comment: `android.widget.EditText` seems to be accessing the native android element. If its a webview you are dealing with could you inspect element using **chrome://inspect/#devices** and share the html here please.

Comment: @nullpointer  Thanks for the help.You are right (Y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Facebook login through the app:

   - you can use UIAutomatorViewer to get view ids like [here](https://cdn-standard.discourse.org/uploads/appium/original/2X/1/15e45fd0761097671f0ba190218546204d31d2e6.jpg), from [this](https://discuss.appium.io/t/unable-to-locate-log-in-button-of-facebook-android-app-using-appium/5750/4) discussion;
   - you don't even need to "getDriver().context(contextName);" in this case (but not sure);
2. Facebook login through WebView:

   - you have to [debug the WebView](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) (as a browser) to get needed elements xpath;
   - with the elements xpath (in my case email field xpath was "//*[@id='u_0_2']") you can search for a field 
     `WebElement element = driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='u_0_2']")` and then click on it or type something whatever;
3. Don't have any solution if it's in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Click Facebook login button which is native :

```
wd.findElement(By.id("com.hathy.fblogin:id/login_button")).click();
```

Switch to webview context :

```
//here we getting the list of context
Set<String> contextHandles = wd.getContextHandles();
for (String s : contextHandles) {
System.out.println("Context : " + s);
//if context contains webview then set the webview context
if (s.contains("WEBVIEW")) {
wd.context(s);
}
}
```

Do Facebook Login Flow in webview :

```
wd.findElement(By.xpath()).sendKeys("//input[@name='email']""<your_emailid>");
wd"//input[@name='pass']"".findElement(By.xpath()).sendKeys(<your_password>"); // test password
wd.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@name='login']")).click();
WebDriverWait driverWait = new WebDriverWait(wd, 10);
driverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@name='__CONFIRM__']"))); // waiting for the element to be clickable
System.out.println(wd.getPageSource()); // get the page source 
wd.findElement(By.pathx("//button[@name='__CONFIRM__']")).click(); //  this step login process is done.
```

Come back to Native view :

```
// here i need to get the context again
Set<String> contextHandles2 = wd.getContextHandles();
for (String s : contextHandles2) {
System.out.println("Context : " + s);
if (s.contains("NATIVE_APP")) {
wd.context(s);
}
}
```

Youtube video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AcBzbhQgDis

Comment: This youtube link does not work, can you replace it with the working link?

Comment: @GeorgePantazes sorry, yes that was wrong link, please check this out , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AcBzbhQgDis . And also check out my channel for new updates in Appium here : https://www.youtube.com/c/TechTockTech